# Corrupted Lenovo Ideapad 3 15IIL05 Touchpad Driver

Tags: windows, laptop, drivers, windows-11, touchpad

A few months ago, I used [Driver Booster 10](https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php) to update my drivers on my Lenovo Ideapad 3 15IIL05 running Windows 11. I didn't make a backup because I did not have the pro version. After I updated my drivers using the program, I immediately noticed that my touch pad was completely unresponsive - even after multiple restarts.

After some research, I decided the best move would be to delete my touchpad driver (I believe it's called *HID-Compliant Touch Screen* or *HID-Compliant Touch Pad*) and hope that it was automatically reinstalled when I restarted my laptop again. It was not.

After that, I was stuck without a touchpad driver. I found out that this problem has happened to many people on similar machines through more research, and combed through forum posts like these:

- [My touchpad drivers are missing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/my-touchpad-drivers-are-missing-and-it-doesnt-work/74663567-8d75-4501-96b9-a516e9a05e04) in Microsoft Answers -forum
- [Lenovo Touchpad Not Working After Driver Booster](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/Lenovo-Touchpad-Not-Working-After-Driver-Booster/m-p/5112697) in Lenovo forum
- [Driver booster 9 broke my touchpad](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/Lenovo-Touchpad-Not-Working-After-Driver-Booster/m-p/5112697) in reddit

I tried using Lenovo's official tools:

- [Automatic driver update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/3-series/ideapad-3-15iil05/downloads/automatic-driver-update)
- [Lenovo system update 5.07.0131](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/hr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/3-series/ideapad-3-15iil05/81we/81we0016us/pf2cj67b/downloads/ds012808-lenovo-system-update-for-windows-10-7-32-bit-64-bit-desktop-notebook-workstation)

None of these tools worked. My final hope was to install the driver manually. For my model, the only drivers under the "Mouse, Touchpad, Keyboard and Pen" section are [Fn and Function Keys drivers](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/3-series/ideapad-3-15iil05/81we/81we0016us/pf2cj67b/downloads/driver-list/component?name=Mouse,%20Touchpad,%20Keyboard%20and%20Pen).

I tried both of these anyway, and neither of them worked. My sister also has a Lenovo laptop with the exact same model (my mom bought us both 2 of the same laptop). I used [MajorGeeks Double Driver](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/double_driver.html) to export the driver from my sister's laptop, then sent the exported driver to my device using a file sharing service and used Double Driver to install it. However, it said the driver failed to install (probably because Double Driver only exported drivers compatible with the machine they were exported from, due to registry keys or something like that).

After that, I gave up. I had no other ideas. About half of the people I found on forums were able to solve the issue by [Rolling back the driver within Driver Booster 10](https://www.iobit.com/product-manuals/db-help/). However, I had already deleted the driver and restarted my machine, and it wasn't showing up in Driver Booster 10 after I scanned again. Again, I had not backed it up because I did not have the pro version of Driver Booster 10.

My laptop's warranty is expired, and I have given up. I've been using a mouse for months, and I hate it. It decreases my productivity when doing things such as programming. If someone could help me, it would be amazing!

Comment: I do not use Driver Booster on Lenovo machines.  See if you can uninstall the driver (Programs and Features or Device Manager).  Then restart and install the Touchpad driver via Lenovo System Update.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you linking to https://www.stackoverflow.com/ - that is not a Base64 Encode / Decode Online

Comment: I took the trouble of decoding the body and editing your question, considering that your decoder link was wrong. I also fixed the links using the link button - those long-a$$ weblinks in the middle of the text made reading it a decoding task all by themselves. I also linked to the Lenovo system update page itself instead of the direct `.exe` file download - if the site has an automatic spambot, I'd expect it to remove direct executable download links, so next time maybe not, please. On the same go I noticed that current system update version is **5.08.01**. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same equipment. Try all the solutions: reinstall the drivers, use third-party programs that promised to solve the problem. I finally managed to solve it in a somewhat obvious way, the Driverboster program usually creates automatic backup copies of the entire system. So, I pressed the start button and wrote “restore point” and upon entering the program there was a history of automatic restore points. then look for a date before the update and manage to access an older version. I hope it helps you, the Driverbooster program by default makes backup copies and creates restore points.